# Как конвертировать unix epoch в data при обновлении записи?

Tags: sql, postgresql

В PostgreSQL мне надо обновить дату в колонке даты. Значение в базе хранится в формате date. Но от клиента дата поступает в unix формате. Как мне конвертировать unix значение даты в формат date?

Comment: Базово вам нужна функция `to_timestamp`, затем нужно понимание как поступает запрос от клиента и где вы можете сделать конвертацию этой функцией. В вопросе не хватает деталей для этого.

Comment: Какой формат вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: @Мелкий клиентское приложение на reactjs. Там оператор выбирает дату в календаре и полученная дата отправляется на сервер (php) в unix формате например дата 1522789200 (для пользователя это 4 апреля 2018, правда со смещением временной зоны +3). Конвертацию желательно бы делать прямо в запросе sql на сервере.

Comment: @RomanC в postgresql есть формат DATE

Comment: @cheerful Какой драйвер вы коннекнитесь к бд?

Comment: @RomanC через пдо. Но я уже нашел решение to_timestamp(:unix)::date (где :unix это дата в unix формате)

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл сам ответ.

to_timestamp(:planterminUnix)::date

где :planterminUnix это число представляющее дату в формате unix epoch.

1. Сначала конвертируем в timestamp
2. Затем кастуем к date